# Universal Quantified Statement being equivalent when variables are swapped

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I was given this statement and asked to express this with universal quantifiers.

Likes(x,y) is a Binary Relation that means that person x likes person y.

The statement given was:

"Everybody is liked by somebody*". Easy Enough, or so I thought?  I put:

∀x∃y, (Likes(y,x)). Apparently this is wrong and the correct solution (that a TA displayed as the answer) is ∀y∃x (Likes(x,y)).

For clarity my question is generally :

is ∀x∃y, (P(y,x)) ≡ ∀y∃x, (P(x,y)) ?

I understand the variables are swapped, but i believe that it is logically equivalent, as i just made the "everbody" labled as x and the "somebody" labeled as "y".

Thank you!

Comment: Those statements are logically equivalent, but surely the correct answer to the original problem is $\forall x\exists y\ \text{Likes}(x,y)$.

Comment: Ah yes. My bad. I meant the statement to be the following: "Everybody is liked by somebody"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent.

To actually formally show this, use the following two equivalences:

$$\forall x \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall y \ \varphi(y)$$

$$\exists x \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \ \varphi(y)$$

where $\varphi$ is any formula, and where $\varphi(x)$ is the same as $\varphi(y)$, but with all free variables $x$ and $y$ swapped.

With these, we can do:

$$\forall x \exists y P(y,x) \Leftrightarrow \forall z \exists y P(y,z) \Leftrightarrow \forall z \exists x P(x,z) \Leftrightarrow \forall y \exists x P(x,y)$$